# What does orthogonality between two vectors really represent?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, triangles, orthogonality

The Pythagorean Theorem states that:

$$\|c\|^2=\|a\|^2+\|b\|^2 $$

Now because in general two vectors $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal if and only if:

$$\|u-v\|^2=\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2 $$

If the sum of the squared length of two vectors is equal to the difference of the squared length of the two vectors, then do the two vectors form a right angle?

Comment: Yes of course.  This follows from the law of cosines

Comment: This is the definition of orthogonality - from there you derive the equation. You start with the right angle - you are not concluding it is a right angle. Necessary and sufficient condition makes both direction justified.

Comment: Okay, but I want to understand why two vectors are said to be orthogonal if what I wrote is true.